# XSLT relative or absolute paths, unexpected behavior

Tags: xslt, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I have this XML code

```
<data>

<proteins>
<protein>
<accession>111</accession>
</protein>
</proteins>

<peptides>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
</peptides>

</data>
```

and this XSLT code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="peptide" 
                             use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root><xsl:apply-templates select="/*/proteins/protein"/></root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="protein">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="../../peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="peptide[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="peptide"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is this one

```
<root>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>AAA</sequence>
    </peptide>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>BBB</sequence>
    </peptide>
</root>
```

Now, the same XSLT code but with almost all paths changed to absolute

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" 
                             use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <root><xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein"/></root>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
        <xsl:apply-templates
    select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]"/>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="peptide"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

does not change anything. However, if the last path is also expressed as absolute

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" 
                             use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <root><xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein"/></root>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
        <xsl:apply-templates
    select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]"/>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the ouput is simply

```
<root></root>
```

I did not expect this.

And, also unexpectedly (for me) if I write the template match before, the output is again the wished one

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" 
                             use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <root><xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein"/></root>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
        <xsl:apply-templates
    select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide"/>
  <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The last files: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu

I would like to understand the logic behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Michael alluded, the issue is one of [template conflict resolution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict). Changing the match pattern from `peptide` to `/data/peptides/peptide` raises the priority of the template to the same level as the template for handling `/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]`. There are nodes in the document that could be selected by either/both of those match patterns, which results in a template conflict.

It is technically an error to have more than one matching template rule, but processors generally recover by applying the last matching template in the document, which is why changing the order of the templates produced different results.

As Michael would well know, Saxon produces the following warning:

```
Recoverable error 
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /data/peptides[1]/peptide[1]
Matches both "/data/peptides/peptide" on line 16 of file:///C:/sandbox/so.xsl
and "/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()= generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession,
  '|', sequence))[1])]" on line 13 of file:///C:/sandbox/so.xsl
Recoverable error 
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /data/peptides[1]/peptide[4]
Matches both "/data/peptides/peptide" on line 16 of file:///C:/sandbox/so.xsl
and "/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()= generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession,
  '|', sequence))[1])]" on line 13 of file:///C:/sandbox/so.xsl
```

Comment: Then, if it should be considered an error, is there an alternative? Or in other words, is the behavior of processors robust in deciding which rule applies?

Comment: @Gerard - It should be. The spec mandates it: "An XSLT processor may signal the error; if it does not signal the error, it must recover by choosing, from amongst the matching template rules that are left, the one that occurs last in the stylesheet." http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

Answer (score 4):

If every node that matches match="x" also matches match="/a/b/c/x", then the only effect of changing the former to the latter is to change the priority of the rule; the rule is considered to be more specific, therefore higher priority, which may cause it to be fired when a node matches more than one rule.